Examining the function.
Given function: $$f(x)=|x+2|e^{-\frac{1}{|x|}}$$

Find constants $a, b$ and $c$ such that $f(x)= ax +b+\frac{c}{x}+ o(\frac 1x)$ when $x \rightarrow +\infty$ and $x \rightarrow -\infty$?
Examine the function and then graph it.
Examine function differentiability.
Determine the equation of the tangent on the function graph at the point $(1, f(1))$

I understand how parts 2. and 3. are done but have never encountered 1. and 4.
2.
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
-(x+2)\cdot e^{\frac{1}{x}}, & x<-2\\
(x+2)\cdot e^{\frac{1}{x}}, & -2\le x<0\\
(x+2)\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{x}}, & x>0
\end{cases}$$
Domain for these functions is $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus {0}$ and I would graph only parts of the functions corresponding to their domain.

I check the critical points $x=-2$ and $x=0$ but since $x=0$ isn't part of the domain (and therefore $f$ is not continuous at that point) I would exclude this part. For $x=-2$, I swap it into the left derivative (of the first function) and do the same for the right derivative (of the second function). I get that they're not matching for $f'(-2)$ and conclude that the function is not differentiable at $x=-2$.

These are my brief explanations of thought process for 2. and 3.
The ones remaining are 1. (which I haven't encountered before but looks like a Taylor expansion) and 4.

What is $\sigma$ is it $o()$ ?

for $(1)$ use Taylor expansion and for $(4)$ use the fact that the slope is given by the derivative

@EDX Yes, it's little o notation used for Taylor and Maclaurin expansion

@SineoftheTime I know it's Taylor expansion in question but it looks rather confusing. I'm not sure what would $x \rightarrow \infty$ and $x \rightarrow - \infty$ mean as well as what formula for expansion to use? Can you explain a bit more in depth please, because if I knew it were that obvious I wouldn't even question it.

@DaniloJonić I've added an answer, let me know if it's clear now

As $x\to +\infty$, let $t=1/x$ and use the expansion of the exponential around $t=0$:
$$e^{-\frac1x}=e^{-t}=1-t+\frac{t^2}2+o(t^2)=1-\frac1x+\frac1{2x^2}+o\left(\frac1{x^2}\right) $$
Now, multiplying by $(x+2)$ you get the desired result:
$$(x+2)\left(1-\frac1x+\frac1{2x^2}+o\left(\frac1{x^2}\right) \right)=1+x-\frac3{2x} +o\left(\frac1x\right)$$
Apply the same method for $x\to -\infty$.
